# How to override behaviour of ResetWindowsAction in netbeans open IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, openide

I was trying to customize the reset window click action under menu items in netbeans platform using netbeans open IDE. Current implementation of netbeans clears up all the top components of property mode and output mode except for editor mode and explorer mode.

My requirement is to keep the output mode and explore mode minimized even after clicking 'reset windows' using "Actions/Window/org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-ResetWindowsAction.instance".

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a Netbeans plugin which will:

1. Remove the current ResetWindowsAction reference in the Window menu
2. Implement your own action (which can have the same "Reset Windows" display name) and add a reference to it in the Window menu

It's much easier than you may think: create a Netbeans module and an Action. Netbeans Action wizard will do all the plumbing stuff. This "official" [netbeans plugin creation tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html) explains you how to do the plugin creation and task 2.

For task 1, in Netbeans, open your module > Important Files > XML Layer > this layer in context > Menu Bar >  Window, select the "org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-ResetWindowsAction" entry and Delete.

For information the code of the current ResetWindowsAction is [here](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/platform/core.windows/src/org/netbeans/core/windows/actions/ResetWindowsAction.java).